# Excel Cell Properties document

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a list of Excel VBA Cell Properties and methods.
These were so easy to find but now they seems as secret as Russian street maps.

Comment: Use the Object Browser in Excel.

Comment: Thanks. It was on the VBA page. Apparently that is now called "Activating a module"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN Range Object Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel)

Cell uses the Range Properties and Methods

Comment: I like Paul Kelly's site as well for good examples https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-range-cells/